# How to stub method returning Long in Spock?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have been trying to stub method returning Long but all I get is null. Is there a way to do this?

```groovy
interface Clock {
    Long currentTimeMillis();
}

def "stub method returning long"() {
    Clock clock = Mock(Clock)
    clock.currentTimeMillis() >> 1

    when:
    Long currentTime = clock.currentTimeMillis()

    then:
    currentTime == 1
    1 * clock.currentTimeMillis()
}

def "mock method returning longs"() {
    Clock clock = Mock(Clock)
    clock.currentTimeMillis() >>> [1, 2, 3]

    when:
    Long currentTime = clock.currentTimeMillis()

    then:
    currentTime == 1
    1 * clock.currentTimeMillis()
}
```

In both tests I'm getting following error:

```
Condition not satisfied:

  currentTime == 1
  |           |
  null        false
```

Comment: Have you tried `clock.currentTimeMillis() >> 1L` not sure if it will help tough

Comment: @tim_yates yes, I did with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You both mock and record the behavior, it should be defined as below.

Here's how it works:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*


class Test extends Specification {
    def "stub method returning long"() {
        given:
        Clock clock = Mock(Clock)

        when:
        Long currentTime = clock.currentTimeMillis()

        then:
        currentTime == 1
        1 * clock.currentTimeMillis() >> 1
    }

    def "mock method returning longs"() {
        given:
        Clock clock = Mock(Clock)

        when:
        Long currentTime = clock.currentTimeMillis()

        then:
        currentTime == 1
        1 * clock.currentTimeMillis() >>> [1, 2, 3]
    }
}

interface Clock {
    Long currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: FYI. We can also have mock/stub defined in `given` block instead of `then`, if readability matters. :)